# java assertions for postconditions

Tags: java, assertion

I am trying to learn about Java assertions. I have the following method and I want to add a post-condition assertion. I am not sure if what I did is correct, can anyone make it clear for me and tell me if it's right, or if not why?

`chain` is a list of the blocks that make up the chain with each block represented by an array of bytes.

```
boolean addBlock (byte[] block) {

    // Prepare for correctness check
    byte[] last = getLast();
    byte[] last_data_hash = new byte[hash_size];
    byte[] current_link_hash = new byte[hash_size];
    for (int i=0; i < hash_size; i++) {
        last_data_hash[i] = last[hash_size+i];
        current_link_hash[i] = block[i];
    }

    if (Arrays.equals(current_link_hash,last_data_hash)) {
        // if it is correctly linked, add it
        chain.add(block.clone());
        return true;
    } else // if it is not correctly linked, don't add it
        return false;

    assert (chain == null) : "chain list: " + chain ;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
boolean addBlock (byte[] block) {

        // Prepare for correctness check
        byte[] last = getLast();
        byte[] last_data_hash = new byte[hash_size];
        byte[] current_link_hash = new byte[hash_size];
        for (int i=0; i < hash_size; i++) {
            last_data_hash[i] = last[hash_size+i];
            current_link_hash[i] = block[i];
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(current_link_hash,last_data_hash)) {
            // if it is correctly linked, add it
            chain.add(block.clone());
            **assert (chain == null) : "chain list: " + chain ;**
            return true;
        } else // if it is not correctly linked, don't add it
            return false;


    }
```

Comment: Either way, your function will return (either `true` or `false`) before it gets to the `assert` statement. You'll need to lift this to be above the return statements. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage-control

Comment: hmm okay, so like now its correct? thank you btw!! @cmbuckley

Comment: That looks like it might work!